# subplots only plotting 1 plot using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I am trying to get two plots on one figure using matplotlib's `subplots()` command. I want the two plots to share an x-axis and have one legend for the whole plot. The code I have right now is:

```
observline = mlines.Line2D([], [], color=(1,0.502,0),\
markersize=15, label='Observed',linewidth=2)
wrfline=mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black',\
markersize=15, label='WRF',linewidth=2)
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,1,sharex='col',figsize=(18,10))
df08.plot(ax=axes[0],linewidth=2, color=(1,0.502,0))\
.legend(handles=[observline,wrfline],loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.9315, 0.9598),prop={'size':16})
axes[0].set_title('WRF Model Comparison Near %.2f,%.2f' %(lat,lon),fontsize=24)
axes[0].set_ylim(0,360)
axes[0].set_yticks(np.arange(0,361,60))
df18.plot(ax=axes[1],linewidth=2, color='black').legend_.remove()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
axes[1].set_ylim(0,360)
axes[1].set_yticks(np.arange(0,361,60))
plt.ylabel('Wind Direction [Degrees]',fontsize=18,color='black')
axes[1].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.05, 1)
plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize=18,color='black')
#plt.savefig(df8graphfile, dpi = 72)
plt.show()
```

and it produces four figures, each with two subplots. The top is always empty. The bottom is filled for three of them with my 2nd dataframe. The indices for each dataframe is a datetimeindex in the format YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS. The data is values from 0-360 nearly randomly across the whole time series, which is for two months.

Here is an example of each figure produced:

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure that the index for df08 and df18 matches? Outside of that I am not sure what would be the problem.

Comment: Yes, they are both the same type of index as well as the same time increments and time range.

Comment: If you display the image after plotting df08, but before plotting df18 does it show on the graph?

Comment: Yeah, so you were actually correct in the first post. While it actually displays, (that is, if it were read line by line), the same length as the other dataframe, it was storing duplicates somehow. When I concatenated the two dataframes together, then called the keys one at a time to plot, it would work out beautifully. Thank you.